# Retrieving Data from Databse with OOP and MySQL Function?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am building a small web tool to track all calls maked by callcenter agents. I would like to know, how to write the code in an effective way, so that changes can be done very easy later on. But since I am very new to OOP, I am struggling with this bit of code. What am I doing wrong?

```
 //DB Connection
class _GlobalFunctions {

  //Querys
  public function getfromDB($query_string) {
  global $mysqli;
  $mysqli->query("SET lc_time_names = 'de_DE'");
  if($query = $mysqli->query($query_string)) {
          return $query;        
          } else {
        return 0;
        }
  }
}

//Tasks
class _Tasks extends _GlobalFunctions {

    public $overdue = "";
    public $open = "";
    public $done = "";

    private function OverdueTasks() 
       {
          $query = getfromDB('SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE taskstst =0 AND  taskduedate < NOW() AND taskrspnsble ='.$_SESSION["user_id"]);           
          if ($query){
              $this->overdue = (int)$query;
              }  else {
                  $this->overdue = 'n/a';
                  } 


       }  

       public function OpenTasks() 
       {
           $query = 'SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE taskstst =0 AND  taskduedate > NOW() AND taskrspnsble ='.$_SESSION["user_id"];
            return $this->getfromDB($query);

       }   
}


//Output
$tasks = new _Tasks;                                    

if(!empty($tasks->overdue)) { 
    echo  $tasks->overdue;
};
```

Comment: Whcih errors do you get? Describe the problem you're having

Comment: hi, am not getting any errors... am getting back nothing!

Comment: run your query directly on mysql and check to see if your query is actually returning results, check that `$_SESSION["user_id"]` has a value

Comment: i run the query in mysql and it gives me the desired results. The session give me the id of the current logged in user also?